# How do I go about making a wrapper for a driver to be used on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, drivers

**The situation:**

I found myself in need of an additional NIC for my pfSense router/firewall.  I had a few choices...

1. shell out over $100 for a dual port gigabit card
2. buy a new motherboard that has dual ports on it
3. buy a 2U server case so I can make use of the remaining PCI slots on the existing motherboard (and thus also buy more single port NICs)

   or
4. use a USB NIC.

The cheapest of the 4 was to go USB, so I bought one.  However, as I read through what I was getting into, I read a bit too fast.  The drivers that are available are for: Mac, Windows, and Linux.  Not bad... But, FreeBSD and hence pfSense, won't use any of those drivers.

So, I find myself in a position to either scrap the NIC for later use, come up with some kind of a wrapper for one of the existing drivers, or worst case would be writing a whole new driver.  If I bench the NIC, I'm stuck with purchasing more expensive hardware, and unless someone convinces me otherwise... writing a completely new driver is a bit more of a challenge than I think I'm up to.  That leaves making a wrapper as my best option.

**The Question:**

Does anyone have any helpful advice on where to start with making a wrapper for drivers to be used in FreeBSD? Are there already turn key solutions for doing this that I just haven't found?

The USB NIC uses the [Asix Chipset AX88179](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112).

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you had a thorough look through the FreeBSD project's [USB-related mailing list](http://search.gmane.org/?query=ASIX&author=&group=gmane.os.freebsd.devel.usb&sort=date&xFILTERS=Gos.freebsd.devel.usb---A) yet?  (I cannot find anything for the ASIX USB3 things there, but maybe you'd be better off [contacting them](http://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-usb).)

Comment: You could also try to add your usb ids to if_axe.

Comment: So far here is where I'm at... I found a way to make the Windows driver work under FreeBSD using NDISgen. The version of pfSense I have is using FreeBSD 8.1 as its base.  So, I downloaded an old ISO for 8.1, used NDISgen, loaded the driver, and SHAZAM! the NIC works under 8.1 without any issues.  I figured just moving the compiled driver over to the pfSense machine and then loading it would be a piece of cake.  Not so.  When I load it I get an execute error.  So, something is different between the two.  Still trying to figure out what though. Let me know if you have ideas where to look.

Comment: Make sure the pfSense and FreeBSD systems are based on the same OS version and architecture.  If pfSense is i386 and your FreeBSD install is amd64, it won't work.